# Using 'Object method'. What is wrong with this code that do not print the full name

Tags: javascript, object, methods

The purpose is to create a code to print the "full name" of the property using an object method. Based on the concept: An **object method** is an object property containing a function definition.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <p>Creating a JavaScript Object.</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
        var person = {
            firstName : "John",
            lastName  : "Doe",
            age       : 50,
            eyeColor  : "blue",
            fullName  : function() {return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;}
        };

        var x = person;
        y = x.fullName; // the function is returning the function definition 

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "Full Name: " + y;
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You tell us. What happens when you run it? What errors do you get?

Comment: did you trying *invoking* the function?  - i.e. `y();`

Comment: I don't think you're calling the function `fullName` in `y = x.fullName();`

Comment: @ochi Calling `y();` wouldn't work. `y.call( x )` would.

Comment: @Paulpro right you are!!! - thank you

Answer (score 4):

You need to operate the function fullName like this:

```
y = x.fullName()
```

Comment: Thank you, just missing the (). It works. Thank you again Daniel.

Answer (score 3):

You need pass result of execution, not function itself

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>Creating a JavaScript Object.</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    var person = {
        firstName : "John",
        lastName  : "Doe",
        age       : 50,
        eyeColor  : "blue",
        fullName  : function() {return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;}
    };

    var x = person;
    y = x.fullName();

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "Full Name: " + y;
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not invoking the `fullName` function, so where you have `y = x.fullName` replace it with `y = x.fullName()`